# How to use ejs's include instead of ejs-mate's include?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm using ejs 2.4.1 and ejs-mate 2.3.0 which uses ejs 1.0,

So in ejs2.4.1, `<%- include('user/show', {user: user}) %>` is supported, but is not supported by ejs-mate.

Is there any way to use ejs's include while using ejs-mate?

Something like `<%- ejs.include('user/show', {user: user}) %>` ??

Another question will be any other ejs-mate alternative supports ejs2?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to set your `view-engine` to `ejs-mate`.

in your `app.js`:

```
app.set('view-engine','eje');
```

Change to:

```
app.set('view-engine','ejs-mate');
```